# Analyzing serial communication that may not be fully RS-232 compliant?

Tags: java, serial-port, embedded, uart

I have an old java program that is communicating with an embedded device manufactured in 2000. The program communicates with this device using the standard Windows serial stack (from what I can tell, when I capture data using PORTMON in windows I see requests like `IRP_MJ_WRITE` and `IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_RTS`).

The device however, connects to a serial port on the computer using a Serial-to-Stereo Plug connector, similar to [this](http://www.carlmcmillan.com/serial_cable_pinout.htm). I believe this means the device itself is only capable of sending signals using two pins.

How can I analyze raw communication between the two devices in an attempt to reverse engineer the protocol? I am on Windows, but am capable of moving to OS X or *unix. I know at some point I am going to have to write something to deal with the specifics of how the device communicates, but what do you guys recommend for gathering information?

Comment: A stereo plug/jack is sufficient for a three-wire RS232 link (TxD, RxD, gnd).  Use a scope to verify voltage levels, and try to measure the baud rate.

Comment: Baud rate appears to be 1200, that is what the setup program sets on the Windows sided things before trying to communicate. The setup program then prompts the user for a serial, which if entered and valid is sent to this embedded device to verify it matches. I see the serial in ASCII fine if I connect to the serial port with putty, it's just padded with data on both sides and I would like to get a raw capture of what that data is for analysis.

Comment: *"Serial"* is not a noun, it's an adjective. *"The setup program then prompts the user for a serial,..."* -- A serial *what*?  *"I see the serial..."* -- Serial data?  Besides the baud rate, you need to determine the other configuration parameters: data length, parity, and stop bits.  Determine if the data is all ASCII or binary.

Comment: Sorry serial is referring to the serial number of the device, which is transmitted in ASCII. I should have made that more clear, my mistake. The data it is padded with however, doesn't appear to be ASCII, as the terminal is having a hard time translating it. Can it be a mixture?

Comment: *"Can it be a mixture?"*  -- It certainly can.  See if PuTTY can log or capture the received data or session to a file (most terminal emulator programs have this capability).  Then look at the the log/capture file with a hex editor.  Someone else can probably come up with a realtime monitoring program.

Comment: @crims0n The data probably consists of non-printable characters. Try the "Show hex" option on Portmon.

Comment: Just get a decent terminal program which can show hex.

Comment: The padding is more usually called *framing* and there were many commonly used formats and a plethora of *ad-hoc* schemes implemented at the whim of the software engineer. A typical style of framed message might be `02 30 39 39 39 39 CC 03` where the message `9999` is enclosed by `STX` and `ETX` (`02h` and `03h`) with a preamble specifying a block type say `0` (`30h`), then your serial number `9999` and a checksum byte. A 3-wire system running at 1200 baud should be adequate, handshaking and/or flow control can be done with software, as part of the message protocol.

Answer (score 2):

The stereo jack is just a cheap way to implement a minimal RS-232-based connection. That shouldn't affect monitoring.

Portmon should display the data you need to investigate the protocol. The `IRP_MJ_WRITE` requests contain the data sent to the device, while the `IRP_MJ_READ` requests contain the data sent by the device.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot do this by software interception means, a simple multi-channel logic analyze (such as one of the FX2 USB designs) should be able to capture traffic on both the transmit and receive lines, and then allow you to software decode this at leisure to see the full interplay of transmissions, responses, and any delays in between.